# Stub for a single function in module

Tags: python, python-2.7, nose, stub

I have next structure of a project:

```
# A.py
def foo():
    result = None
    # some long, very long calculations
    return result

# B.py
from A import foo
def bar():
    result = foo()
    # some not so long and complex calculations
    return some_other_result

# test.py
import A
import B

def setup_module():
    A.foo = lambda: return "Hello"

def test_foo():
    assert B.foo() == "Hello"
```

But, this didn't work, because in `B` the `foo` is being imported directly.

How can I stub the `A.foo` function?

**Note:** I can't edit `A.py` and `B.py`. Only the files for tests, so no change from `from A import foo` to `import A` and usage of `A.foo` in `B.py` is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the function before importing `B`:

```
import A

def setup_module():
    A.foo = lambda: "Hello"

def test_foo():
    import B
    assert B.foo() == "Hello"
```

That way, `A.foo` has already been replaced by the time `B` imports `A.foo`.